# Are WSOP hand logs available to the public?

Tags: poker-theory, wsop

Are there any textual logs available to be read? Obviously there are the video records, but that's not really what I seek here. My search turned out nothing, so I am skeptical there are any. I would love to go over the hands played at WSOPs (mainly final tables), do so statistics etc.

Edit: I don't mean I would like the exact hole cards for every hand. I am curious what the player actions were and what cards were shown at showdown. Anything above would be a sweet bonus.

Comment: Well, you could visit http://www.wsop.com/ and you might find your answer.

Comment: @StellaMarch Could you post the exact link please? At the time of posting this question (Feb 7 '12) it was not available.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say: **no, this does not exist**

Short of hands that are blogged about on various poker news sites, this is virtually impossible. There are thousands of people playing and only a very small percentage of hands played are ever recorded anywhere (either by bloggers or by camera). Even if they were all taped, it would take a massive amount of effort to transcribe the action into text format. Given the near-zero payout for doing this, that's a huge expense with no upside -- not gonna happen.

Comment: Oh I guess you are right about that. I should have stressed I'm most interested in the final table. Certainly would not be that hard to write down one table, so there's slight hope a record exists.

Comment: Yeah, I agree - a final-table-only record is much more possible (to the point of being relatively likely), though I don't know of anywhere that actually does it.

Comment: I smell a new market for an OCR program that can read all hands placed up to the hole cam!

Comment: @CheckRaise They are using RFID now, apparently... and obviously somebody or something is already reading the hands, at least the ones they show on TV.

Comment: They are reading hole cards now with RIFID.  Reading the table would not be hard.

Answer (score 0):

It exists in a form. Not selected hands but every hand from a few selected players, whom they could find that would let them record their hands and play. I was there and met Tom Simms and Andy Bloch. (This Andy Bloch died of a heart attack I believe around 2000 and is not the same Andy Bloch current pro poker player)

From Tom Simms [Personal Website](http://www.west-point.org/users/usma1955/20228/SHS/TES.htm)

> I was probably the first to record play-by-play accounts of final
>   table action at major poker tournaments which I did at the 1996, 1997
>   and 1998 World Series of Poker. My internet reports are archived on
>   the   [ConJelCo](http://ConJelCo.com) World Series of Poker  site and included  [The Andy
>   Bloch Project](http://www.conjelco.com/wsop97/bloch.html)
>     .